# How to split value from string and place it in other field

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I have the following data and I would like to split my data into multiple columns using Oracle SQL

Example:

```
SAM BRICKLER JR ABC
CILLEY III DEF, GHIJ
CRANSTON R GESELL SR ABC DEF GHI
```

Expected Result:

```
Field 1.             Field 2.    Field 3
SAM BRICKLER         JR          ABC
CILLEY               III         DEF,GHIJ
CRANSTON R GESELL    SR          ABC DEF GHI
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting yourself, the press of the format button was not enough..

Comment: To split the fields, there must be a set pattern while in your sample data there doesn't seems any pattern. Do you have any business rules to achieve above result.

Comment: There is no way that I, as a human even, could figure out where to split this string that would match your expectations. How would you anticipate a computer could do it? There's no pattern here. The first column that we split to could be 1, 2, 3 (or more) words long, then the second column we hope gets some value like `SR` `JR`, `IV`... but what is the logic to divine that from this string? Is there a set list of values that you would plunk into that second column that we could use for this logic, splitting the string on everything left/right of one of these found values? Is there any pattern?

Comment: @Ankit. Yes there is a business pattern where I need to split suffixes from the name. But the issue here is, suffixes are coming as part of names without any delimiters and certain pattern

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution assuming that the data you posted is contained in a single column (which I called name_1) in a table (which I called table_1).

This is only possible if ALL names in your table have a suffix (JR, SR, III, etc).
If ALL names have a suffix, then you can use that as your delimiter, since there is a very small set of possible suffixes.

If you only have JR, SR, and III in your table, then this will work:

```
Select * from
(
SELECT  name_1,
        CASE WHEN name_1 LIKE '%JR%' THEN SUBSTR(name_1, 0, INSTR(name_1,'JR')-1) 
        END as Name,
        CASE WHEN name_1 LIKE '%JR%' THEN SUBSTR(name_1, INSTR(name_1,'JR'),2)
        END as Suffix,
        CASE WHEN name_1 LIKE '%JR%' THEN SUBSTR(name_1, INSTR(name_1,'JR')+3) 
        END as Rest_of_data
from table_1 

UNION

SELECT  name_1,
        CASE WHEN name_1 LIKE '%III%' THEN SUBSTR(name_1, 0, INSTR(name_1,'III')-1) 
        END as Name,
        CASE WHEN name_1 LIKE '%III%' THEN SUBSTR(name_1, INSTR(name_1,'III'),3)
        END as Suffix,
        CASE WHEN name_1 LIKE '%III%' THEN SUBSTR(name_1, INSTR(name_1,'III')+4) 
        END as Rest_of_data
from table_1

UNION

SELECT  name_1,
        CASE WHEN name_1 LIKE '%SR%' THEN SUBSTR(name_1, 0, INSTR(name_1,'SR')-1) 
        END as Name,
        CASE WHEN name_1 LIKE '%SR%' THEN SUBSTR(name_1, INSTR(name_1,'SR'),2)
        END as Suffix,
        CASE WHEN name_1 LIKE '%SR%' THEN SUBSTR(name_1, INSTR(name_1,'SR')+3) 
        END as Rest_of_data
from table_1
) a
WHERE Name IS NOT NULL
```

Result:

```
NAME_1                              NAME                SUFFIX         REST_OF_DATA
-------------                       ---------           -------        ------------
CILLEY III DEF,GHIJ                 CILLEY              III            DEF,GHIJ                
CRANSTON R GESELL SR ABC DEF GHI    CRANSTON R GESELL   SR             ABC DEF GHI   
SAM BRICKLER JR ABC                 SAM BRICKLER        JR             ABC
```

Note that you need to have a separate CASE block for every suffix.  So if your table has more suffixes (say, II or IV), then you will need to add a case block for each one to the query, until you have covered all of them.  Keep in mind the string length of each, as I had to change the adjustments after INSTR depending on the length of each suffix string.

I repeat, this will only work if EVERY name has a suffix.  If there are names without suffixes, then you have no delimiter and this cannot be done at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, As JNevil also guessed that JR, SR, III maybe the splitter, I have the following query for you:

```
-- DATA
WITH CTE_MATCH AS
(SELECT 'JR' AS SPLITTER FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'SR' AS SPLITTER FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'III' AS SPLITTER FROM DUAL),
CTE AS
(
SELECT 'SAM BRICKLER JR ABC' MY_STRING FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'CILLEY III DEF, GHIJ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CRANSTON R GESELL SR ABC DEF GHI' FROM DUAL
)
-- YOUR QUERY
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(MY_STRING, '(.*?)( '
                             || SPLITTER
                             || ' |$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS FIELD1,
    SPLITTER   AS FIELD2,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(MY_STRING, '(.*?)( '
                             || SPLITTER
                             || ' |$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1) AS FIELD3
FROM
    CTE
    JOIN CTE_MATCH ON INSTR(MY_STRING, ' '
                                       || SPLITTER
                                       || ' ') > 0;
```

**Output:**

```
FIELD1                FIELD2 FIELD3                          
--------------------- ------ ------------
SAM BRICKLER          JR     ABC                             
CILLEY                III    DEF, GHIJ                       
CRANSTON R GESELL     SR     ABC DEF GHI
```

Cheers!!